# Left join two tables with a default value when no match is found in the right table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I am trying to come up with a c# linq to left join two sql tables with a default value set when no match is found

In Months table I have following data

```
MonthId Name
1       Jan
2       Feb
3       Mar
4       Apr
5       May
```

mData has below Data

```
MonthId Count 
1       10    
2       20
3       5
```

and I am expecting an outcome like below

```
   Name     Count 
    Jan       10    
    Feb       20
    Mar       5   
    Apr       0
    May       0
```

I have below query which returns only when a match is found

```
from p in Months
    join g in mData on p.MonthId equals g.MonthId
    select new {
    p.Name,
    g.Count
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to throw the result of the join into a group and call `DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
from p in Months
    join g in mData on p.MonthId equals g.MonthId into monthData
    from md in monthData.DefaultIfEmpty(new MData{Count = 0})
    select new {
        p.Name,
        md.Count
    }
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179(v=vs.110).aspx) is the MSDN for `DefaultIfEmpty()`

Comment: What is "MData" in DefaultIfEmpty?

Comment: `MData` would be the class generated by Entity Framework